# What's the difference between rbx-2.0.0-rc1 and rbx-2.0.0-dev?

Tags: ruby, rbenv, rubinius

On rbenv (ruby-build), what's the difference between rbx-2.0.0-rc1 and rbx-2.0.0-dev?

I came across https://twitter.com/veganstraightedge/status/315641493245267969 , but that made me more, rather than less, confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rbx-2.0.0-rc1 is the Release Candidate 1 of Rubinius 2.0.0. rbx-2.0.0-dev is the development version of Rubinius 2.0.0, IOW whatever the HEAD of the Git repository happens to be when you run ruby-build.